# Access Subform in a Subform I can not access to the field value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a problem regarding an Access Project.

Indeed, I have a subform `sub2` within a subform `sub1` which is in a main form `main`.

In `sub2`, I have a button that opens a new form created from a SQL query. This query is using in its "where" the value of a field of `sub2`.

The opening of the new form is good when I am only using `sub2`.

However, when I am doing the exact same thing through the `main` form, `sub2` requires me to enter a data instead of automatically opening the new form.

My SQL query is 
`SELECT Livres.*`
`FROM Livres`
`WHERE (((Livres.ID_livre)=[Formulaires]![Livre_sub]![ID_livre]));`

Livre_sub is sub2
ID_livre is the field value

[image: sub2]
[image: main form]

[image: Msg when I execute from the main form]

[image: Dynamic form]

Comment: Show us both code samples (good and bad) and tell us where they are located.

Comment: Mandatory task before posting question; websearch on question title. Reveals answer > 99%.

Comment: I tried everything for hours it has never worked

Comment: Are you using Navigation Form?

Comment: yes my main form is a Navigation Form

Answer (score 1):

The query object has to reference through main form and 2 subform containers. Something like:

`mainformname.subformcontainername.Form.subformcontainername!fieldname`

Don't use dynamic parameterized query. Use WHERE argument of OpenForm method.

`DoCmd.OpenForm "formname", , , "ID_livre=" & Me.ID_livre`

Comment: It's almost working when I use the OPenForm method. The problem is that sub 2 is a dynamic form and the Me.ID_livre is always the same whatever the button I chose

Comment: Button is on sub2 and code is in that button Click event. Me.ID_livre should come from record that has focus. What do you mean by 'sub2 is a dynamic form'? Edit question with relevant info.

Comment: I have edited my post. I want the button "plus" to pass different value to the new form depending of which button is clicked

Comment: I can't understand why it's always passing the same ID_livre. Do I have to change anything in the receiving form?

Comment: Did you remove WHERE clause from query used as form RecordSource? I presume so if you no longer get the input popup. No, AFAIK, nothing else needs to change but since I can't review your db, can't be certain.

Comment: I removed the Where in my SQL query.

Comment: ID_livre is an integer can it be troublesome?

Comment: No, integer is simpler than text. Suggested code works for me with the same form arrangement.

Comment: When I am in a debug Me.ID_livre is always equal 6

Comment: I cannot replicate issue therefore cannot advise why won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The generic syntax is:

```
[Forms]![NameOfMainForm]![NameOfSubform1CONTROL].[Form]![NameOfSubform2CONTROL].[Form]![NameOfControl]
```

Comment: does the fact that my main form is a navigation form change anything?

Comment: My main form is "Menu", sub1 is Recherche_livre and sub2 is Livre_sub and I want "ID_livre" field.

Comment: Then, I believe, your "main" form is the navigation form, but I don't use the navigation form setup.